# Updating Dash Datatable through callback

Tags: python, plotly, python-3.7, plotly-dash

I would like to update my Dash data_table based on an interval. It will run but nothing is updating. I don't think this should be hard but I am clearly missing something. Here is what I have:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table
import time
import pandas as pd
```

data component

```
def getData():
"""
Only can hit api every 6 seconds for 14 total items, 
which is relevant towards the Dash interval  
    """
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        for item in list:
            data  = *hit api*
            df = df.append(data)
            time.sleep(7)
        return df
```

dash component

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# passing in just column names to avoid needlessly hitting API 
tblcols=[{'name': 'col1', 'id': 'col1'},
     {'name': 'col2', 'id': 'col2'}, 
     {'name': 'col3', 'id': 'col3'}      
     ]

app.layout = html.Div([
      html.H4('Dashboard Name'),
      dcc.Interval('graph-update',interval = 500000, n_intervals = 0),
      dash_table.DataTable(
              id = 'table',
          data = [{}],
          columns=tblcols )])

@app.callback(
        Output('table','data'),
        [Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')]
        )
def updateTable(n):

     """
     calling the get data function
     """

     updated_data = getData()
     return updated_data.to_dict('records')

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Again, this will run and return the column headers which I pass but when I see that the update has ran in Console ""POST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1"", nothing changes

Comment: You have `for item in list:` but I don't see where `list` is defined. It's also generally not advisable to use a protected name like that. Your loop will `sleep` for 7 seconds before beginning again. How long are you waiting? Your loop will run as many times as there are values in `list`, so it could run for minutes before returning a value.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that you return an empty `dataframe`. This is because you do `df.append(data)` instead of `df = df.append(data)`

This is a simplified and working code (Dash v1.6.0):

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

def getData():
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for idx in range(10):
        data  = {'x': np.random.random(1)[0], 'y': np.random.random(1)[0]}
        df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
    return df.to_dict('records')

tblcols=[{'name': 'x', 'id': 'x'},
         {'name': 'y', 'id': 'y'}, ]

app.layout = html.Div([
      html.H4('Dashboard'),
      dcc.Interval('graph-update', interval = 1000, n_intervals = 0),
      dash_table.DataTable(
          id = 'table',
          data = getData(),
          columns=tblcols)])

@app.callback(
        dash.dependencies.Output('table','data'),
        [dash.dependencies.Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')])
def updateTable(n):
     return getData()

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run_server(debug=False)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response. I had left out df = df.append(data) in the questions code but it was present in my actual code. The issue ended up being I needed to do a callback for Output('table','columns') as well as having the interval large enough to accommodate the time it takes for the getData() function.

Comment: @Tony, tried with same code for dataframe gets MySQL, but it shows me blank table. Is their any other way to do callback from database??